# What does "id <someType> variableName" mean in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm working through some Cocoa tutorials and ran across this syntax and have no idea what it means. From the context I'm assuming that you're setting a strong-type for the variable.

```
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo name];
```

I've found that by removing the `<someType>` syntax still allows me to send the `[sectionInfo name]` message. So clearly the compiler recognizes the object at id is still the proper type regardless.

[Link to tutorial.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: In Objective-C, an variable of type `id` means that the object it will hold can an instance of *any* Objective-C class, so you can call **any** method and the compiler will not complain.

Comment: Additionally, Objective-C is **not** a strongly-typed language, under any circumstances, so even something like `NSNumber *a = @"Hello"; NSArray *b = a; [(NSMutableDictionary *)b setObject:@"asdf" forKey:@"something"];` will compile, albeit with warnings, and will only crash when you try to call `setObject:forKey` on an object that doesn't implement that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
id sectionInfo;
```

This means that `sectionInfo` is an instance of any class.   It will respond without warning to any method declared anywhere visible to the compiler (which is why bare `id` types are to be avoided).

```
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo;
```

This declares that `sectionInfo` will *only respond (maybe -- some may be @optional) to the methods declared in the `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo` protocol*.   Attempting to call any other method will generate a warning, as you've discovered.

A better declaration would be something like:

```
MySpecificClass<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> *sectionInfo;
```

This declares that `sectionInfo` implements the protocol `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo` *and* is an instance of `MySpecificClass` (or subclass).   The compiler will allow any method call specific to that class (or superclass) *and* any method in the `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo` protocol.

Comment: In this case, of course, you can't declare with a `MySpecificClass`, because you're receiving an object from UIKit and the specific class is private. But when you can, you certainly should declare the class.

Comment: Not entirely true, @BrentRoyal-Gordon.   You are absolutely correct that the specificity of the variable definition is more specific than the API implies.   Unfortunately, this is oft necessary in Objective-C because the `(id)` type leaks into the API in many places.  As a result, we have to apply discipline in our designs and liberally sprinkle `assert([returnObject isKindOfClass:...])` throughout our code.

Comment: Thanks bbum. Makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 3):

It means that variableName can be of any kind of class but has to implement the someType protocol

Comment: Almost.  See my answer.   tl;dr The compiler treats a protocol on an `id` type as *only methods from the protocol are allowed*, which is different than an un-protocol'd `id` declaration.